# How to transpose a table in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, transpose, unpivot

I have a table like

| ID | NAME | CURRENT_DATE | SOURCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | NULL | 2023-01-01 | A |
| 5 | JESSICA | 2023-02-01 | B |

that I want to transpose the table so that the result would look like

| FIELD | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID | 5 | 5 |
| NAME | NULL | JESSICA |
| DATE | 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 |

where I can compare the fields based on the SOURCE column. Is there a way I can do this? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2):

If you have `CURRENT_DATE` as a column name which is a snowflake [reserved keyword](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/reserved-keywords); you need to [escape it using double quotes](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00007Tuca5SAB/how-to-escape-reserved-words-in-a-query) while using as a column_name in query

The following query using [PIVOT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot) and [UNPIVOT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/unpivot) in snowflake shall give you expected output.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT FIELD, SOURCE, VALUE
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
  UNPIVOT (VALUE FOR FIELD IN (ID, NAME, "CURRENT_DATE"))
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(VALUE) FOR SOURCE IN ('A', 'B')
);
```

Output :

| FIELD | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID | 5 | 5 |
| NAME | NULL | JESSICA |
| DATE | 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 |